# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'customerNumber' doesn't have a default value - hibernate and jpa

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am working on Spring Hibernate JPA example. In this example I am simply trying to insert the record into database, but when trying to do that resulting in below. Why?

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:310)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.save(Unknown Source)
    at net.javabeat.springdata.CustomerTest.createCustomer(CustomerTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2987)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3499)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:833)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:817)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:821)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:889)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'customerNumber' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1901)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186)
    ... 82 more
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
@NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int customerNumber;

    private String addressLine1;

    private String addressLine2;

    private String city;

    private String contactFirstName;

    private String contactLastName;

    private String country;

    private double creditLimit;

    private String customerName;

    private String phone;

    private String postalCode;

    private String state;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="salesRepEmployeeNumber")
    private Employee employee;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Order
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Order> orders;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Payment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    private List<Payment> payments;
    // setters and getters
}
```

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Employee e")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeNumber;

    private String email;

    private String extension;

    private String firstName;

    private String jobTitle;

    private String lastName;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Customer> customers;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="reportsTo")
    private Employee employee;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Office
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="officeCode")
    private Office office;
    // setters and getters
}
```

SpringContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- For consider the using of annotations foe defining Spring Bean -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- For bootstrapping the Spring Repository -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="net.javabeat.springdata.repository" />

    <!-- Load database.properties file -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <!-- Enable Transaction Manager -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Necessary to get the entity manager injected into the factory bean -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- ====== MYSQL DataSource ====== -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.jdbc.userName}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ====== Hibernate JPA Vendor Adaptor ======= -->
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.vendor.adapter.show_sql}"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.vendor.adapter.generateDdl}"/>
        <property name="database" value="${jpa.vendor.adapter.database}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- ======== Entity Manager factory ======== -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- Data Source -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <!-- JPA Vendor Adaptor -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>

        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.javabeat.springdata.*" />

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop> -->
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop> --> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

CustomerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:SpringContext.xml")
/*@Transactional*/
public class CustomerTest {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;


    @Test
    public void createCustomer(){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustomerNumber(498);
        customer.setCustomerName("John Kerr");
        customer.setContactLastName("Kerr");
        customer.setContactFirstName("John");
        customer.setPhone("11.22.3333");
        customer.setAddressLine1("500 Street");
        customer.setAddressLine2("Green Tree Hills");
        customer.setCity("London"); 
        customer.setState("United Kingdom");
        customer.setPostalCode("233214");
        customer.setCountry("England");
        customer.setCreditLimit(321312);

        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
}
```

ER relationship diagram attached.
[image]

**Edit-1**

```
mysql> desc customers;
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| customerNumber         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| customerName           | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| contactLastName        | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| contactFirstName       | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone                  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| addressLine1           | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| addressLine2           | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city                   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state                  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| postalCode             | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country                | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| salesRepEmployeeNumber | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| creditLimit            | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc employees;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| employeeNumber | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lastName       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| firstName      | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| extension      | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email          | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| officeCode     | varchar(10)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| reportsTo      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| jobTitle       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDL would be more helpful in this case, but the message is very clear - you are trying to insert row, but the id is not being generated (even though you are using `@GeneratedValue` set to `AUTO`, see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#AUTO)).

Are you trying to map to an existing DB schema? If yes, check if the mentioned field is set to support MySQL [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Please see Edit-1, DB tables are not created AUTO_INCREMENTS

Comment: Then you will need to either assign ids in the application, or alter the tables so that they are using AUTO_INCREMENT, e.g. `ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY customerNumber INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: Ok, I removed @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) from each model and it saved/persist object successfully..

Comment: Yes, because you are assigning the IDs yourself. But if you would really like to use the `@GeneratedValue` annotation you should set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the database table's primary key. But your way it will work as well, but it is not very common to manually assign keys in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your test, you are setting customer number.

`Customer customer = new Customer();
   customer.setCustomerNumber(498);`

As you marked GeneratationType as Auto, I  think you are not supposed to set customer number.